# How to use sweet alert with Ember.js and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, sweetalert

I'm an Ember noob and have been having some trouble getting sweet alert to work with an ember/rails application. I believe I have a scope issue that I'm not quite sure how to handle..

Inside my controller I have a delete action with the following code inside:

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?"
  text: "You will not be able to recover this post!"
  type: "warning"
  showCancelButton: true
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
  closeOnConfirm: false
}, ->
  @get('model').destroyRecord().then =>
    @transitionToRoute 'posts'
  swal("Deleted!", "Your post has been deleted.", "success")

)
```

I trace the error to the '@get('model').destroyRecord().then' and I am pretty sure it is because I am calling 'this.get' inside a function that is inside of a controller action. However, I don't know how to fix that... How do I reference the controller within a function? Any suggestions on how to correct this or a better way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about coffescript, but maybe you can try assigning the controller to a variable?

```
controller = this; // or @ ? 
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?"
  text: "You will not be able to recover this post!"
  type: "warning"
  showCancelButton: true
  confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55"
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
  closeOnConfirm: false
}, ->
  controller.get('model').destroyRecord().then =>
    controller.transitionToRoute 'posts'
  swal("Deleted!", "Your post has been deleted.", "success")
)
```

Comment: I don't think you can declare variables in an ember controller though... I just tried it to make sure and got an error.

Comment: what do you mean? you can just `var controller = this;' or whatever the coffescript equivalent its.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out! Thanks for the tip. I realized that I had to create the controller variable in the delete action rather than in the general controller.

Answer (score 0):

use behavior: in data as :

`<%= link_to "Delete", s, :method => :delete, data: { behavior: 'delete' } %>`

```
$("[data-behavior='delete']").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete " , 
        text: "You will not be able to recover this data!", 
        type: "warning", 
        showCancelButton: true, 
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55", 
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!", 
        closeOnConfirm: false 
    }, function(isConfirm) { 
        if (isConfirm)  
        { 
           // here you can use ajax to delete 
           swal("Deleted!", "Ok , rooms will be delete after submit.", "success"); 
        } 
        else  
        { 
           return false;            
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I got this after 2 hours research and google as well :P